# Border pushes scrollbar beyond viewport

Tags: css, scrollbar, border

My left border is pushing my scrollbar partway behind the right edge of the browser. It's a problem in Chrome and IE8/9.

Here's the 2 styles I have applied to BODY:

```
border-left : black 7px solid;
overflow-y : scroll;
```

Would applying border to something other than BODY help?

Comment: Could you add a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating the problem? (And yes, it probably would help to add the border to a different element... The best way to find out would be to *try* it.)

Comment: I can't replicate the problem with jsfiddle. Here's my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/JCAFd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to the top of your stylesheet and declaring a width on the bordered element should resolve the issue:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```